# Why are my Episerver jobs failing when running automatically or run by the scheduler?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, episerver

I'm using Episerver to run various jobs on an intranet website, and almost all of these jobs will fail to run automatically, but will work just fine when I run them manually.

99% of the time, this is the error message I get: **Could not load file or assembly 'Midco.CMS.Intranet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

If I'm actually missing an assembly, then how is my job able to run manually?

The same code was run automatically on previous publishes of our site, but is now failing. I've tried creating a 'dummy' principal role with admin privileges, hoping that would allow the job to run, I've looked online for other solutions, and have tried debugging, but I can't find a way to make the jobs run automatically.

Are there any Episerver users out there who know how to get the job to run automatically? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a single server solution or multiple servers?

Comment: What EPiServer version do you use?

Comment: @Lanorkin: EPiServer v7.5

Comment: @HenrikN: We were using 1 server for 2 months, and recently moved our app to 2 different servers. The jobs continue to fail despite the transition.

Comment: Could you post some code, put it in a pastebin or something. There are lots of mistakes one can make in these kinds of scenarios. I.e. if I recall it correctly 7.5 doesn't resolve `SiteDefinition.Current` when run as a job but it is resolved when run manually. However, bring the code!

Comment: @SammyPayne I'm asking as the error message indicates that there is an assembly missing. If you have multiple servers there may be an issue with one of the servers but not the other. So running it manually might just be a red herring and the real reason why it works then and not when run on a schedule is that they are being executed on different servers.

Comment: @SammyPayne I've run into this problem before when scheduled jobs are run in a load balanced environment, or with a separate server for the CMS from the public website.

Comment: I've also come across a similar problem that was solved by deleting the scheduled job tables in the database (Episerver will recreate them). https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Per-Nergard/Dates/2016/11/weird-scheduled-jobs-not-running-problem/

Answer (score 1):

in order to get the scheduled Episerver jobs to run again, my team had to copy our existing Episerver database to a new database, then delete the old one. When we scheduled the jobs after copying to the new location, they all ran on time, without error, and have been running without issue for about 8 months. It was drastic but it worked.